# Batch Script to test free space of drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, storage

I would like help making a batch script to test if there is a certain amount of storage available in a drive in Winodws 7, thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far, and the **specific** problem you're having. This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```
fsutil volume diskfree C: | find /i "avail free"
```

Comment: even on an empty disk, like a USB stick, this returns a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

I had this squirreled away from a previous request.

```
@echo off
set "low="
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\ /-p 2^>nul') do set "size=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("%size%") do (
if "%%d"=="" set low=1
set gb=%%a
set mb=%%b
)

if %gb%%mb% LEQ 2000 set low=1

If defined low (
echo email here with %size%
echo WARNING: Drive C: has %size% free 
) else (
echo Drive C: has %gb%.%mb% free GB
)
pause
```